# What is the difference between these two instances?

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading, instance

I have this constructor:

```
BaseState::BaseState(const BaseState& s) {
    id = s.id;
    acceptance = s.acceptance;
}
```

and this overloaded operator

```
BaseState& BaseState::operator=(const BaseState& s) {
    acceptance = s.acceptance;
    id = s.id;
    return *this;
}
```

So my question is the following: creating an instance like

```
//primary is a BaseState defined previously    
BaseState* temp = new BaseState(primary);
```

or

```
BaseState* temp = primary;
```

should be the same thing, or is there any difference?

EDIT: `primary` is a pointer
I also have this constructor:

```
BaseState::BaseState(Id v) {
    id = v;
    acceptance = false;
}
```

And I create my instance `primary` like `BaseState* primary = new BaseState(0)`.

Comment: How did you create `primary`? If the first one compiles, the second one won't. And vice versa.

Comment: Avoid pointers, pass by reference or some shared pointer

Comment: @jrok: I created primary like `BaseState* primary = new BaseState(int id);`. I have another constructor with int as a parameter.

Comment: In that case `BaseState* temp = new BaseState(primary);` will be a compiler error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `primary` is a pointer (as your comments suggest), then the first will not compile (unless there's a constructor you haven't shown us that takes a pointer argument). Perhaps you meant:

```
BaseState* temp = new BaseState(*primary);
```

which will dynamically allocate an object an initialise it with the copy constructor.

The second will create a second pointer to the same object, and won't create another object.

If `primary` were an object, not a pointer:

```
BaseState primary;
```

the first will dynamically allocate an object, and initialise it using the copy constructor. You must remember to delete the object once you've finished with it (or, better, use a smart pointer to do that, or avoid `new` altogether) to avoid leaking memory.

The second will not compile (unless there's a conversion operator to convert the object to a pointer, but that would be weird). But the following would:

```
BaseState temp = primary;
```

This will allocate an object in the current scope, also initialising it using the copy constructor. This will be deallocated automatically when it goes out of scope (or at the end of the program, if it's in a namespace scope). You should prefer this to `new`, unless you really do need a dynamic lifetime.

In neither case will the assignment operator be used. Initialisation is not assignment, even if it does use the `=` token.

Answer (score 1):

The `new` operator **will** invoke a copy-constructor.
The assignment of pointers **will not** invoke an assignment operator.

So, in this example, the first one-liner creates a new object as a copy of the first. The second one-liner (assuming the `primary` is of another type here - pointer and not an object, otherwise the code will not compile or you need to define more assignment operators) creates another pointer to the same object.

Comment: Assuming primary is a pointer, too. There is no BaseState copy, but a pointer copy.

Comment: @Dieter Lücking: he didnot present the body of the constructor.